# Problems arising from a paper on the radial symmetry of the global solution of semilinear PDE $\Delta u+f(u)=0$ in $\Bbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

I am reading the paper [1] by Congming Li.

I want to talk about the typical case that the author gives as follows ([1], §1, pp. 590-):

> In this section, we study positive solutions of the following second order elliptic equation
> $$
> \begin{cases}\Delta u+f(u)=0 & \text { in } \Re^{n} \\ u(x) \longrightarrow 0 & \text { as }|x| \longrightarrow \infty\end{cases}\label{1}\tag{11}
> $$
> where $f$ is a $C^{1}$ function with $f^{\prime}(0)<0$.
> We show that:
> **Theorem 1.1** *Any $C^{2}$ positive solution $u$ of (11) is spherically symmetric about some point in $\Re^{n}$, and $u_{r}<0$ for $r>0$, where $r$ is the radial coordinate about that point*.
>
> To prove the above theorem, it is sufficient to prove that $u$ is symmetric in any direction after a suitable shift in that direction and has only one crest in that direction. We do it in the $x_{1}$ direction. We use the moving planes method.
> We first define the following domain
> $$
> \Sigma(\lambda)=\left\{\left(x_{1}, y\right) \in R_{n} \mid x_{1}<\lambda\right\}
> $$
> be the part of $\Re^{n}$ that located in the left side of the plane $x_{1}=\lambda$ with parameter $\lambda$, and define the following functions on it:
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> &v(x, \lambda)=u\left(x^{\lambda}\right)=u\left(2 \lambda-x_{1}, y\right) \\
> &w(x, \lambda)=v(x, \lambda)-u(x)
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> where $x^{\lambda}$ is the reflection point of $x$ about the plane $x_{1}=\lambda$. We prove the theorem by using the moving planes method in the following two steps:
>
> 1. Initial step: $w(x, \lambda) \geq 0$ in $\sum(\lambda)$ for $\lambda$ near $-\infty$.
> 2. Continuation: $w(x, \lambda) \geq 0$ in $\sum(\lambda)$ for $\lambda$ in a maximal interval $(-\infty, \bar{\mu}$ ], and show that $w(x, \bar{\mu}) \equiv 0$ in $\Sigma(\lambda)$ or $u$ is symmetric in the $x_{1}$ direction about the plane $x_{1}=\bar{\mu}$.
>
> **First Step**: Notice that $w(x, \lambda)=0$ for $x \in \partial \Sigma(\lambda)$ and $w(x, \lambda) \geq-u(x) \longrightarrow 0$ as $|x| \longrightarrow 0$, we know that if $w(x, \lambda)<0$ somewhere in $\Sigma(\lambda), w(x, \lambda)$ must achieve its minimum somewhere in $\Sigma(\lambda)$. Assume the minimum achieves at $x_{0}$. It is easy to see that
> $$
> \nabla_x w\left(x^{0}, \lambda\right)=0, \quad\left\{w_{i j}\left(x^{0}, \lambda\right)\right\} \geq 0
> $$
> On the other hand $w(x, \lambda)$ satisfies
> $$
> \Delta w\left(x^{0}, \lambda\right)+f^{\prime}(\xi) w\left(x^{0}, \lambda\right)=0\label{2}\tag{12}
> $$
> where $0<v(x, \lambda) \leq \xi \leq u(x)$. For $\lambda<0, x \in \Sigma(\lambda)$, we know $|x|>-\lambda$, and consequently $f^{\prime}(\xi)<0$ for $\lambda$ near $-\infty$. In this case \eqref{2} is impossible since
> $$
> \Delta w\left(x^{0}, \lambda\right) \geq 0, \quad f^{\prime}(\xi) w\left(x^{0}, \lambda\right)>0
> $$
> We established that $w(x, \lambda) \geq 0$ for $\lambda$ near $-\infty$.
>
> **Second step**: $w(x, \lambda) \geq 0$ in $\Sigma(\lambda)$ holds for $\lambda$ in a maximal interval $(-\infty, \bar{\mu}], \bar{\mu}$ can not be $+\infty$, because $u>0$ in $\Re^{n}$, and $u(x) \longrightarrow 0$ as $|x| \longrightarrow 0$.
>
> We prove $w(x, \bar{\mu}) \equiv 0$. Suppose the contrary that $w(x, \bar{\mu}) \not \equiv 0$. Elliptic equation \eqref{2} and Maximum principle imply $w(x, \bar{\mu})>0$ in $\Sigma(\bar{\mu})$. The maximality of $\tilde{\mu}$ implies that there are sequences $\lambda^{k} \searrow \bar{\mu}, x^{k} \in \Sigma\left(\lambda^{k}\right)$, such that $w\left(x^{k}, \lambda^{k}\right)<0$. Furthermore, as shown in the first step, we can assume
> $$
> w\left(x^{k}, \lambda^{k}\right)=\min _{x \in \Sigma\left(\lambda^{k}\right)} w\left(x, \lambda^{k}\right)
> $$
> which implies
> $$
> \nabla_x w\left(x^{k}, \lambda^{k}\right)=0\label{3}\tag{13}
> $$
> If $\left|x^{k}\right| \longrightarrow \infty$, we must have $u\left(x^{k}\right) \rightarrow 0$, which as shown in the first step, is impossible. Thus we may assume that $x^{k} \longrightarrow \bar{x} \in \overline{\Sigma(\bar{\mu})}$. The fact that $w(x, \bar{\mu})>0$ in $\Sigma(\bar{\mu})$ implies $\bar{x} \in \partial \overline{\Sigma(\bar{\mu})}$. Notice that $w(x, \bar{\mu})$ satisfies equation \eqref{2} with $\lambda=\bar{\mu}$, we can then employ Hopf lemma to obtain $w_{1}(\bar{x}, \bar{\mu})<0$. On the other hand, taking limit in \eqref{3}, we obtain $\nabla_x w(\bar{x}, \bar{\mu})=0$, a contradiction. Thus we must have $w(x, \bar{\mu}) \equiv 0$ in $\Sigma(\bar{\mu})$, or equivalently, $u$ is symmetric in the $x_{1}$ direction about the plane $x_{1}=\bar{\mu}$. Simple calculation shows that $w(x, \lambda)$ can not identically equal to zero for $\lambda<\vec{\mu}$. Thus, as a consequence of Maximum principle and Hopf lemma, we must have $w_{1}(x, \lambda)<0$ for $x$ lies on the plane $x_{1}=\lambda$, or equivalently, $u_{1}(x)>0$ for $x \in \Sigma(\bar{\mu})$. Our proof is completed.

Now **my question**: since we have that
$$
w\left(x^{k}, \lambda^{k}\right)=\min _{x \in \Sigma\left(\lambda^{k}\right)} w\left(x, \lambda^{k}\right),
$$
how this paper proves the fact that $x_{k}$ has a limit as $k \rightarrow \infty$? The paper says that if $\left|x^{k}\right| \longrightarrow \infty$, we must have $u\left(x^{k}\right) \rightarrow 0$ which, as shown in the first step, is impossible. Thus may we assume that $x^{k} \longrightarrow \bar{x} \in \overline{\Sigma(\bar{\mu})}$? Is this enough to say that $x_{k}$ has a limit?

**Reference**

[1] Congming Li (1991), "Monotonicity and symmetry of solutions of fully nonlinear elliptic equations on unbounded domains", Communications in Partial Differential Equations, 16:4-5, 585-615, [DOI:10.1080/03605309108820770](https://doi.org/10.1080/03605309108820770), [MR1113099](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1113099), [Zbl 0741.35014](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0741.35014).

Comment: There's a liberal (and implicit) amount of **taking a subsequence** involved in this argument here. Basically, if $|x^k|$ does not converge to infinity, it must have a bounded subsequence, and by Heine-Boral it must have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering! I'm not very skilled in the methods in this paper, so in my view the proof omits a lot. $w(x, \bar{\mu}) \geq 0$ in $\Sigma(\bar{\mu})$, then construct a sequence $\lambda^{k} \searrow \bar{\mu}, x^{k} \in \Sigma\left(\lambda^{k}\right)$, such that $w\left(x^{k}, \lambda^{k}\right)=\min _{x \in \Sigma\left(\lambda^{k}\right)} w\left(x, \lambda^{k}\right)<0$, then let $k \rightarrow \infty$ then we get $\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty}$ $w\left(x^{k}, \lambda^{k}\right) \le 0$? The first step said that when $x^{k} \rightarrow -\infty$, $w \ge 0$, why this is impossible?

Comment: I would suggest you look at the original paper of Gidas-Ni-Nirenberg Comm. Math. Physics (1979) vol 68, pages 209-243. The proof you copied above is a condensed version of the proof in GNN, and my recollection is that the GNN explanation is pretty clear with details included.